# bash: can read be used as a command or expression?

Tags: bash, shell, unix, zsh

I want to make a oneliner loop that reads and checks what it read.

This surely won't work:

```
while [[ read line != "q" ]]; do; echo "enter q to quit: "; done
```

Zsh here tells me `condition expected: read`.

Perhaps `read` does not even have this concept of a return value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Bash Pitfall #9](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#if_.5Bgrep_foo_myfile.5D):

> if takes a command. [ is a command, not a syntax marker for the if statement. It's equivalent to the test command, except that the final argument must be a ].

`[[` is not special syntax for the `if` condition. `[[` is a command in its own right. Try a loop like this:

```
while read -r line; do
  [[ $line = "q" ]] && break
  # more code
done
```

`read` returns failure when it cannot read an expression, and `[[` is a command, so this works. For more info see http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001.

Note: Suuplying the `-r` switch to `read` is a good idea - it prevents funny things happening to backslashes in the input.

Answer (score -1):

```
while read line; do; [[ "$line" == 'q' ]] && break; done;
```

seems to work.

But I'm not sure why I can't replace `[[ ]]` with `[ ]`, it fails strangely:

```
$ bash
bash-3.2$ while true; do; read line; [ "$line" == 'q' ] && break; done;
bash: syntax error near unexpected token ';'                                       

$ while true; do; read line; [ "$line" == 'q' ] && break; done;
ajlfkj
zsh: = not found
```

Comment: To explain the bash error: `do` can be immediately followed by a command - it does not require a semicolon.

Comment: I can't tell what you mean by "why is it requiring a command". Clarify, please?

Comment: Using a backtick as an opening quotation mark is an old ASCII typesetting convention.

Comment: The `bash` parser treats a newline following a `do` as whitespace, not a command terminator. The `;` can only be treated as a command terminator, which is not allowed immediately after `do`. Your first example, with `[[`, gives the same syntax error as with `[`.

Comment: @michaelb958 I think it was past bedtime when I posted that comment. So bash is actually requiring no semicolon after the `do`, huh?

Comment: @chepner thanks. weird that i was able to get it working with the `do;` somehow

Comment: @StevenLu Correct. No semicolon is required after `do`.